# Using 'setEntity' with 'HttpURLConnection' in android studio

Tags: android-studio, post, httpurlconnection

I want to use `setEntity` in my code with `HttpURLConnection` but **Android Studio** 
 doesn't recognize `setEntity` in my code
and I added  this code to my **Gradle**:
`org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2`
but didn't work for me
here is an image of my code
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvQL4.png)

Answer (score 0):

This has been deprecated so you can't use it anymore or basically not required.[follow link to docs](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html)

To post data, you can write data (queryString) after the connection is opened.The data parameters can be formed as string then, you need to send your data in form of byte, below code converts the data into byte to send

```
String urlParameters  = "param1=a&param2=b&param3=c";
byte[] postData       = urlParameters.getBytes( StandardCharsets.UTF_8 );
int    postDataLength = postData.length;
String request        = "http://example.com/index.php";
URL    url            = new URL(request);
HttpURLConnection conn= (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();           
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
conn.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString( postDataLength ));
conn.setUseCaches(false);
try( DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream( conn.getOutputStream())) {
   wr.write( postData );
}
```